# Unable to run turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py. Tutorial: tf2TutorialsWriting a tf2 broadcaster (Python)

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and I am trying to complete the tf2 tutorials. While running this particular tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing a tf2 broadcaster (Python)) I created the turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py file and the start_demo.launch file exactly as described in the tutorial and in the directory as described in the tutorial. After this, I invoked catkin_make and I source devel_isolated/setup.bash in the terminal (I also tried sourcing devel/setup.bash). However, the following error comes up and it closes:

```
    RLException: Unable to launch [turtle1_tf2_broadcaster-4]. 
    If it is a script, you may be missing a '#!' declaration at the top.
    The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

The full output of the command I have attached at the end.

I am not able to figure out a way to get through this. Please suggest me what should I do. Please also find below my code for turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py and start_demo.launch. On lines 5 and 22 in turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py, I tried changing tf (as mentioned on the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing a tf2 broadcaster (Python)) to tf2 and it still didn't work.

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python  
   import rospy
   
   # Because of transformations
   import tf2_conversions
   
   import tf2_ros
   import geometry_msgs.msg
   import turtlesim.msg
   
   
   def handle_turtle_pose(msg, turtlename):
       br = tf2_ros.TransformBroadcaster()
       t = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
   
       t.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
       t.header.frame_id = "world"
       t.child_frame_id = turtlename
       t.transform.translation.x = msg.x
       t.transform.translation.y = msg.y
       t.transform.translation.z = 0.0
       q = tf2_conversions.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, msg.theta)
       t.transform.rotation.x = q[0]
       t.transform.rotation.y = q[1]
       t.transform.rotation.z = q[2]
       t.transform.rotation.w = q[3]
   
       br.sendTransform(t)
   
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       rospy.init_node('tf2_turtle_broadcaster')
       turtlename = rospy.get_param('~turtle')
       rospy.Subscriber('/%s/pose' % turtlename,
                        turtlesim.msg.Pose,
                        handle_turtle_pose,
                        turtlename)
       rospy.spin()
```

Code for start_demo.launch

```
  <launch>
      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
      <node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>


    <node name="turtle1_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
    </node>
    <node name="turtle2_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
      <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
    </node>

  </launch>
```

Full out put when lunching the start_demo.launch.

```
suyash@ROS:~/tutorial_ws$ roslaunch learning_tf2 start_demo.launch
... logging to /home/suyash/.ros/log/b7a6d97a-f1bb-11e9-a228-08002776bdd9/roslaunch-ROS-2614.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ROS:36971/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3
 * /turtle1_tf2_broadcaster/turtle: turtle1
 * /turtle2_tf2_broadcaster/turtle: turtle2

NODES
  /
    sim (turtlesim/turtlesim_node)
    teleop (turtlesim/turtle_teleop_key)
    turtle1_tf2_broadcaster (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py)
    turtle2_tf2_broadcaster (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2625]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to b7a6d97a-f1bb-11e9-a228-08002776bdd9
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2636]
started core service [/rosout]
process[sim-2]: started with pid [2639]
process[teleop-3]: started with pid [2640]
RLException: Unable to launch [turtle1_tf2_broadcaster-4]. 
If it is a script, you may be missing a '#!' declaration at the top.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[turtle1_tf2_broadcaster-4] process has died without exit code [pid -1, cmd /home/suyash/tutorial_ws/src/learning_tf2/nodes/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py __name:=turtle1_tf2_broadcaster __log:=/home/suyash/.ros/log/b7a6d97a-f1bb-11e9-a228-08002776bdd9/turtle1_tf2_broadcaster-4.log].
log file: /home/suyash/.ros/log/b7a6d97a-f1bb-11e9-a228-08002776bdd9/turtle1_tf2_broadcaster-4*.log
[teleop-3] killing on exit
[sim-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
suyash@ROS:~/tutorial_ws$ ^C
```

Thank you.

With regards,
Suyash

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335625/unable-to-run-turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py.-tutorial:-tf2tutorialswriting-a-tf2-broadcaster-(python)/) by [Suyash](https://answers.ros.org/users/47427/suyash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-18**:
*Always* include links to tutorials, source code, pages etc you're reading, following or copy-pasting.

Without seeing what you're actually doing, we cannot help you.

Seeing the error message you received, please also show us *what exactly* you copied (ie: the contents of your copy of `turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py`).

**Comment by [Suyash](https://answers.ros.org/users/47427/suyash/) on 2019-10-18**:
Thank you for your response, sorry I missed those details. I have edited my question and included the details.Also one more update is I tried doing the tf tutorial as well (http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing a tf broadcaster (Python), and I am still getting the exact same error, so there is something fundamental that I am missing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-18**:
Please show us the *exact contents* of your `turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py`.

And also the output of `ls -al turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py` (run it in the directory that contains the file).

**Comment by [Suyash](https://answers.ros.org/users/47427/suyash/) on 2019-10-18**:
I ran the command and the output was:

```
suyash@ROS:~/tutorial_ws/src/learning_tf2/nodes$ ls -al turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 suyash suyash 1218 Oct 17 18:47 turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py
suyash@ROS:~/tutorial_ws/src/learning_tf2/nodes$
```

I have also copied and pasted the exact contents of turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py. Also I have included full output of roslaunch learning_tf2 start_demo.launch.

**Comment by [Suyash](https://answers.ros.org/users/47427/suyash/) on 2019-10-21**:
Hi there. Is there any update for me on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have figured out the solution. There was around 3 space characters between the start and #!/usr/bin/env python. When I removed the spaces for this line and all subsequent lines, it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Suyash](https://answers.ros.org/users/47427/suyash/) with karma: 16 on 2019-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-24**:\

> There was around 3 space characters between the start and `#!/usr/bin/env python`

This was indeed the reason why I asked you to copy the contents of your script *verbatim*.

Good to hear you figured it out.